# XPath query returns a null node in a legacy C++ system using Xerces-C++ and Xalan-C++

Tags: c++, xpath, xerces, xalan

I have been maintaining a legacy system that uses Xerces-C++ for XML parsing. I have to use Xalan-C++ to achieve full XPath support. I am using Xerces-C++ 3.2.3 and Xalan-C++ 1.12.0 - these versions are compatible with each other

I have been having issues with some code that I wrote based on this example guide: http://www.xatlantis.ch/index.php/blog/19-xml/26-x-path-with-xerces-and-xalan

I have checked other examples, but the above example is the only one I found that uses the XercesDOMParser wrapper. Other examples (including the one provided by Xalan-C++) use Xalan's own DOM implementation. I could technically use that as a very last resort, but I would very much prefer to use the Xerces DOM wrapper.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
std::string xpath = "/some/path/with/namespaces";
const xalanc::XalanDOMString strExpression(xpath.c_str());
xercesc::DOMDocument* document = xml.parser().get().getDocument();
xercesc::DOMNode* root = document->getDocumentElement();

xalanc::XercesParserLiaison parserLiaison;
parserLiaison.setBuildWrapperNodes(true);
parserLiaison.setBuildMaps(true);

xalanc::XalanDocument* xalanDocument = parserLiaison.createDocument(document, false, false);
xalanc::XalanElement* documentElement = xalanDocument->getDocumentElement();
xalanc::XercesDocumentWrapper* xercesDocumentWrapper = parserLiaison.mapDocumentToWrapper(xalanDocument);
xalanc::XalanNode* rootContextNode = xercesDocumentWrapper->mapNode(root);
xalanc::XercesDOMSupport domSupport(parserLiaison);

if(rootContextNode != NULL) {
  xalanc::XPathEvaluator evaluator;
  xalanc::XalanNode* foundXalanNode = evaluator.selectSingleNode(
      domSupport,
      rootContextNode,
      strExpression.c_str(),
      documentElement);

  xercesc::DOMNode* targetNode = NULL;

  if(foundXalanNode != NULL) {
    xercesc::DOMNode const* constTargetNode = xercesDocumentWrapper->mapNode(foundXalanNode);
    targetNode = const_cast<xercesc::DOMNode*>(constTargetNode);
    std::cout << "value: " << targetNode->getNodeValue() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This is the smallest snippet of code I could write to reproduce my problem, I apologise if it feels too big. Let me know if you need clarification on any part of it.

This code compiles successfully, but it does not output anything and it should output the value of an input element. Under further investigation, it seems that *foundXalanNode* is NULL, which tells me that the code is unable to find a node that matches my xpath. I tested the xpath expression I am using in an online browser, and it is correct. I also tested different variations of the xpath without namespaces.

Edit:
As requested, here is an example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns3:header created="2022-04-07T14:19:55.611+01:00" schemaVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="example.org" xmlns:ns2="example.org" xmlns:ns3="example.org">
  <ns3:point schemaVersion="1.1.0">
    <ns2:type>PRODUCTION</ns2:type>
  </ns3:point>
</ns3:header>
```

and here is the XPath I have been testing it with:

```
/ns3:header/ns3:point/ns2:type
```

Comment: Perhaps also show us an XML sample and sample XPath expressions (minimal but complete) that fail. I don't know details of the API you use but I would expect most XPath expressions to be evaluated against the document node/root node itself, not against the root element/document element of the document. That could be one reason why your attempts fail (e.g. you have paths `root/child/grandchild/foo` which would work against the document node but fail with the `root` element used as the context node of the XPath evaluation), the other is obviously namespaces, although you say you checked that.

Comment: Needs more detail, as Martin says we need to see the data and the actual XPaths used. Try `/*` or `/` as your XPath, do they work?

Comment: Question: if your XPath expression includes namespaces, where do you provide the namespace declarations (i.e. the namespace prefix/URI bindings)?

Comment: @ConalTuohy Thanks for your reply, I have included examples of xml and xpath as you and Martin requested. As you can see, the namespaces are defined along with the root element

Comment: Can you build https://github.com/apache/xalan-c/blob/Xalan-C_1_12_0/samples/SimpleXPathAPI/SimpleXPathAPI.cpp and see whether your path and samples works with that C++ sample and perhaps then adapt your code to use similar code? As you have shown absolute paths my doubts about the wrong context node do not apply and I can't really judge how Xalan and Xerces C++ handle namespaces, so for a start I would try using that sample to see whether my XPaths work.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for your reply. Yes, my xml and xpath expressions work with that example code. I suspect that my problem at this stage is that the XPathEvaluator does not produce prefix -> namespace URI mappings. This might be because the prefixes are defined in the root element. I am trying to figure out how to get it to find those prefixes

Comment: I would try e.g. `XalanDocumentPrefixResolver thePrefixResolver(xalanDocument);` and then pass that `thePrefixResolver` as the last argument to the `selectSingleNode` method.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have tried that, and also other classes in the prefix resolver family, but the result did not change.

Comment: Is the Xerces C++ DOM by default namespace aware or do you have to explicitly (as you have to do in Java) request a namespace aware DOM? If so, have you done that for your Xerces DOM document?

Comment: So https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classAbstractDOMParser.html#a1962795fff331583b34b78229364ded7 suggests default DOM parsing might not be namespace aware. What does your `xml.parser().get().getDocument()` do exactly, does it ensure the DOM parser supports namespaces?

Comment: @MartinHonnen `xml.parser().get()` gets a reference to an instance of XercesDOMParser, which calls `setDoNamespaces(true)` prior to this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to adapt the sample I mentioned in the comment to incorporate a Xerces DOM document and have Xalan wrap it; then I have run it against your sample XML with the arguments `sample.xml / /ns3:header/ns3:point/ns2:type` and the output is e.g. `content: PRODUCTION`, meaning the node is found.

The code is

```
#include <xalanc/Include/PlatformDefinitions.hpp>



#include <cassert>


#include <iostream>



#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/framework/LocalFileInputSource.hpp>



#include <xalanc/PlatformSupport/XSLException.hpp>



#include <xalanc/DOMSupport/XalanDocumentPrefixResolver.hpp>



#include <xalanc/XPath/XObject.hpp>
#include <xalanc/XPath/XPathEvaluator.hpp>



#include <xalanc/XalanSourceTree/XalanSourceTreeDOMSupport.hpp>
#include <xalanc/XalanSourceTree/XalanSourceTreeInit.hpp>
#include <xalanc/XalanSourceTree/XalanSourceTreeParserLiaison.hpp>
//#include <parser.h>


#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>

#include <xercesc/parsers/XercesDOMParser.hpp>

#include <xalanc/XercesParserLiaison/XercesDocumentWrapper.hpp>

using namespace XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE;


int
main(
            int     argc,
            char*   argv[])
{
    using std::cerr;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    int     theResult = 0;

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        cerr << "Usage: SimpleXPathAPI XMLFilePath Context XPathExpression" << endl;

        theResult = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        using xalanc::XSLException;

        try
        {
            using xercesc::XMLPlatformUtils;

            using xalanc::XPathEvaluator;


            XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();

            XPathEvaluator::initialize();

            {
                using xercesc::LocalFileInputSource;

                using xalanc::XalanDocument;
                using xalanc::XalanDocumentPrefixResolver;
                using xalanc::XalanDOMString;
                using xalanc::XalanNode;
                //using xalanc::XalanSourceTreeInit;
                //using xalanc::XalanSourceTreeDOMSupport;
                //using xalanc::XalanSourceTreeParserLiaison;
                using xalanc::XObjectPtr;

                XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser;
                parser->setDoNamespaces(true);

                parser->parse(argv[1]);

                DOMDocument* doc = parser->getDocument();

                xalanc::XercesParserLiaison parserLiaison;
                parserLiaison.setBuildWrapperNodes(true);
                parserLiaison.setBuildMaps(true);

                xalanc::XercesDOMSupport domSupport(parserLiaison);

                // Initialize the XalanSourceTree subsystem...
                //XalanSourceTreeInit     theSourceTreeInit;

                // We'll use these to parse the XML file.
                //XalanSourceTreeDOMSupport       theDOMSupport;
                //XalanSourceTreeParserLiaison    theLiaison(theDOMSupport);

                // Hook the two together...
                //theDOMSupport.setParserLiaison(&theLiaison);

                //const XalanDOMString    theFileName(argv[1]);

                // Create an input source that represents a local file...
                //const LocalFileInputSource  theInputSource(theFileName.c_str());

                // Parse the document...
                XalanDocument* const    theDocument = parserLiaison.createDocument(doc, false, false);
                        //theLiaison.parseXMLStream(theInputSource);
                assert(theDocument != 0);

                xalanc::XercesDocumentWrapper* xercesDocumentWrapper = parserLiaison.mapDocumentToWrapper(theDocument);

                XalanDocumentPrefixResolver     thePrefixResolver(theDocument);

                XPathEvaluator  theEvaluator;

                // OK, let's find the context node...
                XalanNode* const    theContextNode =
                        theEvaluator.selectSingleNode(
                            domSupport,
                            theDocument,
                            XalanDOMString(argv[2]).c_str(),
                            thePrefixResolver);

                if (theContextNode == 0)
                {
                    cerr << "Warning -- No nodes matched the location path \""
                         << argv[2]
                         << "\"."
                         << endl
                         << "Execution cannot continue..."
                         << endl
                         << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    xalanc::XPathEvaluator evaluator;
                    xalanc::XalanNode* foundXalanNode = theEvaluator.selectSingleNode(
                        domSupport,
                        theContextNode,
                        XalanDOMString(argv[3]).c_str(),
                        thePrefixResolver);

                    xercesc::DOMNode* targetNode = NULL;

                    if (foundXalanNode != NULL) {
                        xercesc::DOMNode const* constTargetNode = xercesDocumentWrapper->mapNode(foundXalanNode);
                        targetNode = const_cast<xercesc::DOMNode*>(constTargetNode);
                        std::cout << "content: " << XMLString::transcode(targetNode->getTextContent(), XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager) << std::endl;
                    }
 
                }
            }

            XPathEvaluator::terminate();

            XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
        }
        catch(const XSLException&   theException)
        {
            using xalanc::XalanDOMString;

            XalanDOMString  theError;

            cerr << "XSL exception: "
                 << theException.defaultFormat(theError)
                 << endl;

            theResult = -1;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cerr << "Generic exception caught!" << endl;

            theResult = -1;
        }
    }

    return theResult;
}
```

I have used Xalan 1.12 and Xerces 3.2.3. No idea where your approach fails but hopefully the above helps you on your way to get your Xalan XPath evaluation against a Xerces DOM working.